# Understanding "you were sealed for the day of redemption"

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

> And do not grieve the holy Spirit of God, with which you **were** sealed for the day of redemption.

The day of redemption has not occurred yet, then why *were* and not *have been*?

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is saying that you (and presumably everyone) was "sealed  with the holy Spirit of God" at some time in the past, perhaps at birth or baptism. "for the day of redemption" indicates the future **purpose** of this past sealing.

Comment: so what. The present perfect is also used for actions that were done in past but still have an effect on present.   So can't present perfect be used in this case where the action has the effect on some unpredictable future?

Comment: yes that form could be used instead. I was explaining the meaning of the given sentence. I might add that "so what" is not the most congenial of responses.